# Simulator problem (Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037)

Tags: android, flutter

I have did all things wgat sir was told. But after run the simulator I get this error->
[Emulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz4MU.png)

After this when I get to run my app, I get this error->
[Runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeTj0.png)

Now, when I run flutter doctor in cmd then I get no critical issue into there->
[cmd result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck65M.png)
Then what should be wrong with that? I have check stack overflow previous question on that but that answer is very comlicated for me. Because i am new in android app world.

Please,help.

Answer (score 0):

> This is likely caused by insufficient permissions. Run Android Studio
> or your command prompt (whichever you prefer) as an administrator and
> that should solve your problem.

make your SDK up-to-date

Comment: My SDK is upto date. After running Android studio from administrator mode my problem wasn't solved. I get same issue.